# speed up boot time of compute engine instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2016

I've written a simple batch file that starts apache and sends a curl request to my server at start time. I am using windows server 2016 and n-4 compute engine instance.

I've noticed that 2 identical machines require vastly different start up times. One sends a message in just 40s, other one takes almost 80s. While in console, both seem to start at the same time, the reality is different, since the other one is inaccessible for 80s via RD tools.

The second machine is made from disk image of the first one. What factors contribute to the start time? Where should I trip the fat?

Answer (score 0):

The delay could occur if the instances are in different regions and also if the second instance has some additional memory intensive applications or additional customizations done. The boot disk type for the instance also contributes to the booting time. Are you getting any information from the logs about this delay during the startup time? You could also compare traceroute results on both instances to see if there is a delay at some point in the network.